# cannot open connection while exporting the data to database using hibernate

Tags: hibernate

I have written a service to export jcr data to database. The service starts itself when I start the server of my application previously It was exporting the data with no any problem since two days whenever I start the server it get successfull for exporting the data but again I get following exception I tried to find the problem but I could not make it.

23:31:55,562 ERROR [STDERR] org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException: Cannot open connection; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: Cannot open connection
23:31:55,562 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.SessionFactoryUtils.convertHibernateAccessException(SessionFactoryUtils.java:615)
23:31:55,562 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateAccessor.convertHibernateAccessException(HibernateAccessor.java:412)
23:31:55,562 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate.doExecute(HibernateTemplate.java:424)
23:31:55,562 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate.executeWithNativeSession(HibernateTemplate.java:374)
23:31:55,562 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate.saveOrUpdate(HibernateTemplate.java:744)
23:31:55,562 ERROR [STDERR]     at nl.gx.snsbank.jcrreport.dao.PageDAOImp.store(PageDAOImp.java:39)
23:31:55,562 ERROR [STDERR]     at nl.gx.snsbank.jcrobjectsbuilder.PageBuilder.createDomainObject(PageBuilder.java:88)
23:31:55,562 ERROR [STDERR]     at nl.gx.snsbank.jcrobjectsbuilder.PageBuilder.SaveToDB(PageBuilder.java:57)
23:31:55,562 ERROR [STDERR]     at nl.gx.snsbank.service.JCRExporterService.exportToDB(JCRExporterService.java:91)
23:31:55,562 ERROR [STDERR]     at nl.gx.snsbank.service.SchedulerJobServiceImpl.run(SchedulerJobServiceImpl.java:114)
23:31:55,562 ERROR [STDERR]     at nl.gx.snsbank.service.SchedulerJobServiceImpl.scheduleJob(SchedulerJobServiceImpl.java:153)
23:31:55,562 ERROR [STDERR]     at nl.gx.snsbank.service.SchedulerJobServiceImpl.onStart(SchedulerJobServiceImpl.java:78)
23:31:55,562 ERROR [STDERR]     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
23:31:55,562 ERROR [STDERR]     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
23:31:55,562 ERROR [STDERR]     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
23:31:55,562 ERROR [STDERR]     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
23:31:55,562 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.apache.felix.dependencymanager.ServiceImpl.invoke(ServiceImpl.java:484)
23:31:55,562 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.apache.felix.dependencymanager.ServiceImpl.activateService(ServiceImpl.java:441)
23:31:55,562 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.apache.felix.dependencymanager.ServiceImpl.access$000(ServiceImpl.java:44)
23:31:55,562 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.apache.felix.dependencymanager.ServiceImpl$1.run(ServiceImpl.java:113)
23:31:55,562 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.apache.felix.dependencymanager.SerialExecutor$1.run(SerialExecutor.java:47)
23:31:55,562 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.apache.felix.dependencymanager.SerialExecutor.scheduleNext(SerialExecutor.java:84)
23:31:55,562 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.apache.felix.dependencymanager.SerialExecutor.access$000(SerialExecutor.java:33)
23:31:55,562 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.apache.felix.dependencymanager.SerialExecutor$1.run(SerialExecutor.java:50)
23:31:55,562 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.apache.felix.dependencymanager.SerialExecutor.scheduleNext(SerialExecutor.java:84)
23:31:55,562 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.apache.felix.dependencymanager.SerialExecutor.execute(SerialExecutor.java:68)
23:31:55,562 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.apache.felix.dependencymanager.ServiceImpl.calculateStateChanges(ServiceImpl.java:147)
23:31:55,562 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.apache.felix.dependencymanager.ServiceImpl.start(ServiceImpl.java:257)
23:31:55,562 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.apache.felix.dependencymanager.DependencyManager.add(DependencyManager.java:56)
23:31:55,562 ERROR [STDERR]     at nl.gx.webmanager.wcb.foundation.ComponentBundleImpl.startComponent(ComponentBundleImpl.java:621)
23:31:55,562 ERROR [STDERR]     at nl.gx.webmanager.wcb.foundation.ComponentBundleImpl.startComponents(ComponentBundleImpl.java:379)
23:31:55,562 ERROR [STDERR]     at nl.gx.webmanager.wcb.foundation.ComponentBundleImpl.doStart(ComponentBundleImpl.java:211)
23:31:55,562 ERROR [STDERR]     at nl.gx.webmanager.wcb.foundation.ComponentBundleImpl.start(ComponentBundleImpl.java:160)
23:31:55,562 ERROR [STDERR]     at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor123.invoke(Unknown Source)
23:31:55,562 ERROR [STDERR]     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
23:31:55,562 ERROR [STDERR]     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
23:31:55,562 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.apache.felix.dependencymanager.ServiceImpl.invoke(ServiceImpl.java:484)
23:31:55,562 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.apache.felix.dependencymanager.ServiceImpl.activateService(ServiceImpl.java:441)
23:31:55,562 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.apache.felix.dependencymanager.ServiceImpl.access$000(ServiceImpl.java:44)
23:31:55,562 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.apache.felix.dependencymanager.ServiceImpl$1.run(ServiceImpl.java:113)
23:31:55,562 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.apache.felix.dependencymanager.SerialExecutor$1.run(SerialExecutor.java:47)
23:31:55,562 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.apache.felix.dependencymanager.SerialExecutor.scheduleNext(SerialExecutor.java:84)
23:31:55,562 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.apache.felix.dependencymanager.SerialExecutor.access$000(SerialExecutor.java:33)
23:31:55,562 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.apache.felix.dependencymanager.SerialExecutor$1.run(SerialExecutor.java:50)
23:31:55,562 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.apache.felix.dependencymanager.SerialExecutor.scheduleNext(SerialExecutor.java:84)
23:31:55,562 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.apache.felix.dependencymanager.SerialExecutor.execute(SerialExecutor.java:68)
23:31:55,562 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.apache.felix.dependencymanager.ServiceImpl.calculateStateChanges(ServiceImpl.java:147)
23:31:55,562 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.apache.felix.dependencymanager.ServiceImpl.start(ServiceImpl.java:257)
23:31:55,562 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.apache.felix.dependencymanager.DependencyManager.add(DependencyManager.java:56)
23:31:55,562 ERROR [STDERR]     at nl.gx.webmanager.wcb.foundation.ComponentBundleActivatorBase.init(ComponentBundleActivatorBase.java:70)
23:31:55,562 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.apache.felix.dependencymanager.DependencyActivatorBase.start(DependencyActivatorBase.java:76)
23:31:55,562 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.apache.felix.framework.util.SecureAction.startActivator(SecureAction.java:589)
23:31:55,562 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.startBundle(Felix.java:1458)
23:31:55,562 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleImpl.start(BundleImpl.java:774)
23:31:55,562 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleImpl.start(BundleImpl.java:755)
23:31:55,562 ERROR [STDERR]     at nl.gx.webmanager.services.bundlemanager.service.impl.BundleManager.internalStart(BundleManager.java:825)
23:31:55,562 ERROR [STDERR]     at nl.gx.webmanager.services.bundlemanager.service.impl.BundleManager.resolveAndStart(BundleManager.java:534)
23:31:55,562 ERROR [STDERR]     at nl.gx.webmanager.services.bundlemanager.service.impl.BundleManager.handleStateChanges(BundleManager.java:516)
23:31:55,562 ERROR [STDERR]     at nl.gx.webmanager.services.bundlemanager.service.impl.BundleManager.updateBundle(BundleManager.java:425)
23:31:55,562 ERROR [STDERR]     at nl.gx.webmanager.services.bundlemanager.service.impl.BundleManager.createBundle(BundleManager.java:399)
23:31:55,562 ERROR [STDERR]     at nl.gx.webmanager.services.bundlemanager.service.impl.BundleManager.createBundleFromCachedBundle(BundleManager.java:678)
23:31:55,562 ERROR [STDERR]     at nl.gx.webmanager.services.bundlemanager.service.impl.BundleManager.synchronizeBundle(BundleManager.java:655)
23:31:55,562 ERROR [STDERR]     at nl.gx.webmanager.services.bundlemanager.service.impl.BundleManager.synchronizeBundleState(BundleManager.java:630)
23:31:55,562 ERROR [STDERR]     at nl.gx.webmanager.services.bundlemanager.service.impl.BundleManager.frameworkEvent(BundleManager.java:340)
23:31:55,562 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.apache.felix.framework.util.EventDispatcher.invokeFrameworkListenerCallback(EventDispatcher.java:738)
23:31:55,562 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.apache.felix.framework.util.EventDispatcher.fireEventImmediately(EventDispatcher.java:696)
23:31:55,562 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.apache.felix.framework.util.EventDispatcher.run(EventDispatcher.java:900)
23:31:55,562 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.apache.felix.framework.util.EventDispatcher.access$000(EventDispatcher.java:50)
23:31:55,562 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.apache.felix.framework.util.EventDispatcher$1.run(EventDispatcher.java:102)
23:31:55,562 ERROR [STDERR]     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
23:31:55,562 ERROR [STDERR] Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: Cannot open connection
23:31:55,562 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.hibernate.exception.SQLStateConverter.convert(SQLStateConverter.java:67)
23:31:55,562 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.hibernate.exception.JDBCExceptionHelper.convert(JDBCExceptionHelper.java:43)
23:31:55,562 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.hibernate.exception.JDBCExceptionHelper.convert(JDBCExceptionHelper.java:29)
23:31:55,562 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.hibernate.jdbc.ConnectionManager.openConnection(ConnectionManager.java:426)
23:31:55,562 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.hibernate.jdbc.ConnectionManager.getConnection(ConnectionManager.java:144)
23:31:55,562 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.hibernate.jdbc.AbstractBatcher.prepareStatement(AbstractBatcher.java:95)
23:31:55,562 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.hibernate.id.IdentityGenerator$GetGeneratedKeysDelegate.prepare(IdentityGenerator.java:69)
23:31:55,562 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.hibernate.id.insert.AbstractReturningDelegate.performInsert(AbstractReturningDelegate.java:30)
23:31:55,562 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2158)
23:31:55,562 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2638)
23:31:55,562 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.hibernate.action.EntityIdentityInsertAction.execute(EntityIdentityInsertAction.java:48)
23:31:55,562 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.hibernate.engine.ActionQueue.execute(ActionQueue.java:250)
23:31:55,562 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSaveOrReplicate(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:298)
23:31:55,562 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSave(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:181)
23:31:55,562 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:107)
23:31:55,562 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.saveWithGeneratedOrRequestedId(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:187)
23:31:55,562 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.entityIsTransient(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:172)
23:31:55,562 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.performSaveOrUpdate(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:94)
23:31:55,562 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.onSaveOrUpdate(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:70)
23:31:55,562 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.fireSaveOrUpdate(SessionImpl.java:507)
23:31:55,562 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.saveOrUpdate(SessionImpl.java:499)
23:31:55,562 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.saveOrUpdate(SessionImpl.java:495)
23:31:55,562 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate$16.doInHibernate(HibernateTemplate.java:747)
23:31:55,562 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate.doExecute(HibernateTemplate.java:419)
23:31:55,562 ERROR [STDERR]     ... 67 more
23:31:55,562 ERROR [STDERR] Caused by: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Cannot open database "JCRRepository" requested by the login. The login failed.
23:31:55,562 ERROR [STDERR]     at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException.makeFromDatabaseError(Unknown Source)
23:31:55,562 ERROR [STDERR]     at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.IOBuffer.processPackets(Unknown Source)
23:31:55,562 ERROR [STDERR]     at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.processLogon(Unknown Source)
23:31:55,562 ERROR [STDERR]     at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.logon(Unknown Source)
23:31:55,562 ERROR [STDERR]     at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.connectHelper(Unknown Source)
23:31:55,562 ERROR [STDERR]     at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.loginWithoutFailover(Unknown Source)
23:31:55,562 ERROR [STDERR]     at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.connect(Unknown Source)
23:31:55,562 ERROR [STDERR]     at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver.connect(Unknown Source)
23:31:55,562 ERROR [STDERR]     at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:582)
23:31:55,562 ERROR [STDERR]     at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:154)
23:31:55,562 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource.getConnectionFromDriverManager(DriverManagerDataSource.java:174)
23:31:55,562 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource.getConnectionFromDriver(DriverManagerDataSource.java:165)
23:31:55,562 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.AbstractDriverBasedDataSource.getConnectionFromDriver(AbstractDriverBasedDataSource.java:149)
23:31:55,562 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.AbstractDriverBasedDataSource.getConnection(AbstractDriverBasedDataSource.java:119)
23:31:55,562 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalDataSourceConnectionProvider.getConnection(LocalDataSourceConnectionProvider.java:82)
23:31:55,562 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.hibernate.jdbc.ConnectionManager.openConnection(ConnectionManager.java:423)
23:31:55,562 ERROR [STDERR]     ... 87 more

Answer (score 0):

The root cause seems to be:

"com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Cannot open database "JCRRepository" requested by the login. The login failed. 23:31:55,562 ERROR [STDERR] at "

Are you able to manually login to the database?

Comment: Your application can't. So, I'd double check the credentials, server license (does it restricts the number of concurrent connections?), and things like that.